# Quick Google Webmaster Tools API wrapper in PHP

Tags: php, google-search-console

Anybody know of a small php class that works with Google Webmaster Tools API?

Without using Zend Framework. In PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of classes and functions you can borrow from [projects on github](https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=php&q=google+webmaster&repo=&start_value=1&type=Code&x=0&y=0).